# undefined is not and object (evaluating '_props[registrationName]')

Tags: react-native, ontouch

react-native:0.43.3

The problem only occurs in Android system, iOS is fine.
When I touch a TouchableOpacity component, the onTouch function won't be executed.

Anyone found this problem?

I built a Calendar with RN. The problem is that when I click the Day unit on Android devices or emulators I'll get the error *undefined is not and object (evaluating '_props[registrationName]')*. But it's okay to click it on iOS devices and emulators. The Day component' code is like this:

```
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.calendarRowUnit} onPress={() => this.props.onSelect(this.props.date)}>
            <View style={dateWrapperStyle}>
                <Text style={dateTextStyle}>{dateString}</Text>
            </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
```

And the error image:
[error info iamge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lakq.jpg)

**I've found that only when I touch the Text area the error will occur.** 
I don't know it's a react-native bug or my fault. The error never occured before I updated the react-native version to 0.43.3.

Comment: Provide more context please

Comment: Sorry, I only wanted to ask someone who met the problem for more information and I had no idea about it. Maybe I've found the problem. I'll edit the question right now.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
/**
   * @param {object} inst The instance, which is the source of events.
   * @param {string} registrationName Name of listener (e.g. `onClick`).
   * @return {?function} The stored callback.
   */
  getListener: function(inst, registrationName) {
    var listener;

    // TODO: shouldPreventMouseEvent is DOM-specific and definitely should not
    // live here; needs to be moved to a better place soon
    if (typeof inst.tag === 'number') {
      const props = EventPluginUtils.getFiberCurrentPropsFromNode(
        inst.stateNode
      );
      if (!props) {
        // Work in progress.
        return null;
      }
      listener = props[registrationName];
      if (shouldPreventMouseEvent(registrationName, inst.type, props)) {
        return null;
      }
    } else {
      if (typeof inst._currentElement === 'string') {
        // Text node, let it bubble through.
        return null;
      }
      if (!inst._rootNodeID) {
        // If the instance is already unmounted, we have no listeners.
        return null;
      }
      const props = inst._currentElement.props;
      listener = props[registrationName];
      if (shouldPreventMouseEvent(registrationName, inst._currentElement.type, props)) {
        return null;
      }
    }

    invariant(
      !listener || typeof listener === 'function',
      'Expected %s listener to be a function, instead got type %s',
      registrationName,
      typeof listener
    );
    return listener;
  },
```

There's currently a bug where if the `Text` inside the TouchableOpacity has a `number` it will error out. The way to fix it for the moment is to cast the `number` to a `string` and it will trigger the String check and throw a null appropriately.

EX:

Before: `<Text>16</Text>`
After: `<Text>String(16)</Text>`

Comment: I had the same problem ... and indeed this was the right solution. Thank you.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!

Comment: the `String('text')` should be in `{}` like that: `{String(16)}`

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in [#12905](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12905) `<Text />` This bug is specific to RN 0.43.x and has been fixed in later versions. The bug was , Whenever there is a number inside `<Text />` then it will cause this error. 
The fix for this is :

1. Upgrade React Native with latest versions.
2. TypeCast the value to `string`.

For Example,

- `<Text> {100} </Text>` to `<Text> {''100} </Text>`
- `<Text> {100} </Text>` to `<Text> {String(100)} </Text>`
- `<Text> {100} </Text>` to `<Text> {(100).toString} </Text>`